# jQuery Knob throwing a Uncaught TypeError: G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

Hi and thank you in advance.

I am building an app that has to display many charts in one page. I use jQuery Knob for pie charts and Echarts for Line-Charts. I have a page where I use both of these librairies and they seem to conflict each other.

My Knob Charts shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSIuK.png)

[Here's the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNxk6.png)

I instanciate both of my libraries after the body tag in this order:

```
<!--jquery knob -->
<script src="../assets/vendors/material-pro/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="../assets/vendors/material-pro/plugins/echarts/echarts-all.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function() {
     $('[data-plugin="knob"]').knob();
  });
 </script>
```

If I remove the Echart library on my page, the Knob charts work. But I can't make them work together.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: is your issue was resolved? have you any more information about the issue?